# recognize Chrome default favicon and replace it (when there is no stored page favicon)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, favicon

in chrome extension I have list of url's (as nodes), and those nodes have favicons
source for favicons is

```
img.src = 'chrome://favicon/'+ url;
```

problem is, chrome will always return favicon even if it doesn't exist.
It will be default "document" favicon, and I would like to use my custom (if there is no original page favico).
How can I test if there is stored favicon for certain URL, or how to recognize with javascript that Chrome returned default one?
I tried this (for non existing pages favicons)

```
if ('chrome://favicon/'+ url) ....
```

but that if test is always true.

Comment: Interesting question. Chrome devs want to switch away from being able to access `chrome://favicon/` to an API, but [it's not done yet](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=104102).

Comment: I didn't say that; I don't have a ready solution, but it sounds solvable. If anything else, you could try to compare bitmaps to known-default image.

Comment: If you meant to base64 and then comparing them, that's a huge work...for list of couple of hundred nodes... meh...I thought there is a easy trick/way, but if not, I'll use what i have

Comment: @WolfWar do you have to store them on domain `chrome://favicon/`?

Comment: @peterdotjs `chrome://favicon/` is populated by Chrome itself. Collecting own favicon DB will involve invasive spying after every navigation by the user.

Comment: @Xan Yes I know that. I was asking because if they are normal website favicons they will not live on `chrome://`. I'm not clear on what he meant by "nodes". I'm assuming different pages that the extension can serve and thus needs to be accessed through `chrome://`

Comment: @peterdotjs `chrome://favicon/` is Chrome's favicon _cache_.

Comment: @Xan yes i know that....what I'm saying is if you can access the actual url of the fav icon for these pages for example: (`https://www.google.com/favicon.ico`) One can simply check if "chrome://" is serving the icon and then ignore it. Serving the desired default icon instead.

Comment: @peterdotjs You can't guess the favicon URL given just a website URL. In fact, they are not always static images but can be generated by page's code

Comment: @peterdotjs list of nodes, like a bookmarks (favicon, title, url)

Comment: @Xan I was assuming user would have `tabs` permissions and thus has access to the `favIcon` url.

Comment: @peterdotjs For that the page needs to be loaded. OP's use case seems to be just having the URL.

Comment: I'll just let you take it from here. As everything I said kept getting attacked.

Comment: [link](http://prntscr.com/6ev64j) ... those default favicons are unvisited pages (no cached favicons) I want to change them to something else...that's all